# WriteFile to Standard Output fails

Tags: c, winapi

I want to write to a random output, among which `STD_OUTPUT_FILE` can be. I want to use 
`WriteFile`, but it does not seem to write anything.

```
HANDLE outH = GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
WriteFile( outH,param, strlen ( param ), &written_b, NULL );
```

Comment: Does your process have a console?

Comment: Can u show construction of param? Check result of WriteFile() and GetLastError().

Comment: param is ok. I checked it.

Comment: What does "to have a console" mean ? I am running it from a console.

Comment: Debug with WriteFile( outH,"HelloStack\n", 11, &written_b, NULL ); - What happens?

Comment: Also, you should add the debugging steps/results you already took.

Comment: Also, what is in written_b after the call?

Comment: The debug step Charles suggested has no effect. I gate the same return value of 0 and GetLastCode() returns error code 6.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

There was a error in redirecting the standard output in which when it should let it be as it was, it was doing something wrong. Do not know yet. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks any form of error-checking. This is common with code copied from a website or Stack Overflow answer, where the error-checking is often omitted for clarity and brevity. But any time you write code yourself, you absolutely must assume that it can fail and write the code to deal with that case. Here, you know it is failing and you still haven't gone back to add the error-checking code to see where that failure is occurring.

Let's add the error-checking code now, referring to the SDK documentation when necessary to see how the API functions you call handle error conditions:

```
static void ReportError(const TCHAR* errorMsg)
{
   MessageBox(NULL, errorMsg, NULL, MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}

int _tmain(int argc, TCHAR* argv[])
{
   char param[] = "This is some output.";
   DWORD written_b;

   HANDLE outH = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
   if (!outH)
   {
      ReportError(TEXT("No standard handles associated with this app."));
   }
   else if (outH == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      TCHAR errMsg[100];
      wsprintf(errMsg, TEXT("GetStdHandle() failed with error code %lu"), GetLastError());
      ReportError(errMsg);
   }
   else
   {
      if (!WriteFile(outH, param, strlen(param), &written_b, NULL))
      {
         TCHAR errMsg[100];
         wsprintf(errMsg, TEXT("WriteFile() failed with error code %lu"), GetLastError());
         ReportError(errMsg);
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Now, if something goes wrong, we'll not only know it but we'll know *why*.

And good thing, because when I run this code on my computer, it works just fine. The problem therefore lies elsewhere in your application in some of the code we haven't seen. The error-handling code will help flush it out.

Answer (score 0):

To write to STDOUT using the calling window/console, you need to link the resulting executable to the console subsystem.

LINK.exe /EDIT /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE {your exe name here}

This works with the older VB6 environment, I'm assuming the same executable flags apply to Visual C as well.